# What would be a good mongodb schema for a web app with multiple permission types?

Tags: asp.net, database, mongodb, nosql

I'm developing a web app (ASP.NET Core 6) where a user can have access to various work environments, and within those environments, they can have access to multiple workspaces.

Regarding the work environments, a user can be "Admin" or "Worker". This determines whether or not the user will be able to create workspaces within that environment.

On the other hand, the workspaces can be "Public" or "Private". Public ones can be accessed by any user inside that environment, while private ones can only be accessed by authorized users set by the Admin who created said workspace.

I'm finding it hard to define the database scheme in this matter. I was thinking about creating 2 collections to define relations between user and workspace/work environment (`UserId` and `WorkspaceId` or `EnvironmentId`), but I'm not sure if separating it like this is the right approach since workspaces access depends on their work environment access as well.

BTW, this is my first time using MongoDB so maybe I'm not quite understanding how relations work here.

Comment: How many total _Work Environments_ do you expect?  How many _Workspaces_ do you expect in each _Work Environment_?  How many total _users_ do you expect?  What sort of queries do you expect?  [Data Model Design](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/data-model-design/) can be important as to how your future queries will be performant/simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i never use ASP.NET before, but you can join 2 or more collections by perform `lookup` with query `agregation` .
reff: [$lookup (aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

you can also filtering within the `$lookup` and much more.

i create an example how to approach like the your sample data (`UserId` and `WorkspaceId` or `EnvironmentId`)

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BHg1poJNc0f)